# How to organize inference results by model ID that produced it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, devops, inference, kedro

I am creating a deep ensemble, and I need to keep track of which inference results came from which neural network. However, enabling versioning via the Kedro catalog only organizes my inference results by datetime, with each file having an identical name.

What is the best practice for organizing results by model ID? For example, is it possible to customize the versioned folder names, or the versioned file? E.g. `data/07_model_output/model_predictions.json/2020-08-09T20.55.57.237Z-Model-04/model_predictions.json` or `.../2020-08-09T20.55.57.237Z/model_predictions-Model-04.json`

Answer (score 0):

Versioning is intended for keeping track of the versions of a single dataset, not to disambiguate between multiple datasets.

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can use multiple output datasets to keep track of your predictions, i.e. `nn1_predictions.json`, `nn2_predictions.json`, etc.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that my catalog will have several hundred entries.